# Find turtles that are not connected to others in netlogo

Tags: hyperlink, find, netlogo

I have a network with near of 4700 turtles, however not all of them are connected, and that is ok..... but I need to find the ones that are not connected to others (through links) and kill them, how can I do it?

I imagine something like:

""ask turtles with [no-links] [die]""

But... it doesn't work because no-links reports nothing!!... I dont know if it is the correct way (changing the **with** condition) **or I must follow another step.**

PD: all the turtles and their links are set up in a nw context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look into the [netlogo dictionairy](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/), you will see that `no-links` reports an empty link agentset.
There are two reporters you can use for getting the number of links for each turtle: `link-neighbors` or `my-links`:

```
ask turtles with [not any? my-links] [die]
```

or

```
ask turtles with [not any? link-neighbors] [die]
```